# Kill all detached processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a script that gets a wallpaper from Unsplash, then sets it. I setup a flag `--repeat` to continuously get images based on a specified interval. The script functions perfectly but to make this happen I used `& disown` to detach the process so it stays running in the background

My issue is trying to kill the old process(es) when I run the script again. I used to use `kill $(ps -ef | awk '/script_name/{print $2}')` to kill the existing processes. Of course doing this, I can't recommend anyone else use the script.

```
while read line ; do
    case $line in
        *-r*) [[ $line =~ $$ ]] || kill `echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2` ;;
    esac
done < <(ps -ef | grep -w 'bg.sh')
```

I was using this at the top of said script but as of today the processes that spawn aren't named by the script's name, so now I can't figure out a way to find them, let alone kill them; Of course causing above snippets to stop working. I've tried just running `kill $!` at the top of the script but I must be doing something wrong. All the sources I find online have only confused me more

Comment: A common way to solve it is to have `script_name.pid` file where you store the exact pid of the running script.

Comment: How would I go about storing the pid as the process starts? With `$!`?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: I strongly suggest you stop trying to kill things by PIDs at all, and use a lockfile instead. With a flock-style lockfile, you can use `fuser -k` to kill all processes that have it open, without ever needing to look up their PIDs. And `fuser -n -x /path/to/lockfile /path/to/yourscript` will start `yourscript` only if the named lockfile isn't already held, and will exit immediately if it is. (Without the `-n`, it'll wait for the existing processes holding the lock to exit before starting `yourscript`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that sounds like a much better solution. I'll look into `flock`

Comment: BTW, a quick note about `disown` -- it does the work of taking things out of the job table, but the other thing that `nohup` does is redirect any FDs that point to the TTY. So to be completely equivalent to `nohup yourprogram`, it's typically something like `yourprogram </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 & disown -h "$!"` -- of course, `nohup.out` is a horrible default and you should replace it with a program-specific place to store logs. But all this is moot if you switch to a systemd user service, which is what I'd recommend. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill all already running instances of a certain script, you can add something like this at the top of script;

```bash
for pid in $(pidof -x SCRIPT_NAME); do
    if [ "$pid" != $$ ]; then
        kill "$pid"
    fi
done
```

You can also try using `killall` instead of `kill`.

```bash
killall SCRIPT_NAME
```

Comment: Don't routinely use `kill -9`

Comment: Will using only `kill` work?

Comment: Of course; the standard design of Unix tools is to do the "normal" thing without any options (and to document this behavior and the available options in a [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html)). Perhaps see also [useless use of `kill -9`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill); but the exposition there is rather unclear.

Comment: Ok you are right.

Comment: I just tried this and I think it's much better than my inital attempt but it won't kill the old processes because they aren't showing up. When I use `ps -ef | grep 'script_name' `or `pidof -x 'script_name'` nothing shows. I've used this for over a year and always been able to find the pid by it's name, manually killing it. Now I can't even do that

Comment: @wick3dr0se I tested your script form GitHub, and it works fine for me. It kills older instances and I can use `pidof -x bg.sh` to get pid.

Comment: @Keyitdev Thanks for testing it. I'm not sure what the issue is. It worked for me with this code for awhile now and today all of the sudden the processes it spawns cant be identified by the script name.. They are spawning a pid under some name though.. If I run `kill $(ps -ef | awk /a/'{print $2}')` it will kill the bg.sh processes among other things. Whats odd is there is no a in the name at all and I can't find it by searching for the flag or script name like I have been for a long time

Comment: @wick3dr0se Can I get your output? Just run `ps -ef >> log` and send me log.

Comment: @Keyitdev Sorry for the long delay; I just got back to the PC. I'm not sure the easiest way to share logs, so I put it on [GitHub](https://github.com/wick3dr0se/log). This is my full `ps -ef` output after running the script process. I have it ran with `bash bg.sh -r 30 amoled` but querying any of those terms will show nothing on my system

Comment: @Keyitdev I thougt it was working again but the issues is really odd. If I query `ps -ef` for just bg.sh it won't work but if I query something that happens to make it show in `ps -ef` then I can query bg.sh just fine. Just to test it I have a while loop to read lines with `-r` from ps -ef output and I uploaded that in the GitHub links README. The first snippet is first query of `-r` and second is literally just re-ran again but it outputs as expected...

Comment: Very odd issue. So your script is working but with delay?. Maybe try running something like `bg.sh&` and then `ps -ef | grep -- -r` and see if something shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the process id in a `.pid` file. When starting the new script, you can let it read that file and kill the old script.

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PIDFILE=/fixed/path/to/script.pid

if [[ -e $PIDFILE ]]; then               # check if the .pid file exists
    OLDPID=$(<"$PIDFILE")                # read it
    while kill "$OLDPID" 2>/dev/null     # try to kill it
    do
        sleep 1                          # sleep a little
    done
    echo "$OLDPID is dead"
fi

# Store the new pid
trap 'rm "$PIDFILE"' EXIT
echo $$ > "$PIDFILE"

# let the script do what it's supposed to do here
```

You could add a limit to how many times it should try to kill the old script too and do a `kill -0 "$OLDPID"` afterwards just to confirm that it's actually dead.

Comment: I expected this to work since my issue seems to be that I can't access the script's processes by name but multiple processes just build up if I keep running it

Comment: @wick3dr0se, if your goal is to only let one process run at a time, stop trying to use `kill` for that, and use `flock` instead; that's what it's meant for. Or, even better than that, define a systemd service; `systemctl start yourservice` will only start something if it's not already running, `systemctl restart yourservice` will shut down any existing copy before starting a new one, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got the impression this was for restarting, like when the script is to be updated. A service is nice if one has root privs, but I didn't assume OP has.

Comment: @wick3dr0se Is the old pid (the one in the `.pid` file) still alive after you kill it like above?

Comment: @TedLyngmo you are right. Sometimes I run it with different arguments which query differnt image results. It's ran like `bash script.sh amoled -r 30` to get amoled based images every 30 seconds. Then automatically sets it to the wallpaper. Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/wick3dr0se/scripts/blob/master/bg.sh) link to the script

Comment: @TedLyngmo, user services are a thing; you can create `.service` files under your home directory that run as your account (though one needs to use `systemctl --user` to interact with them). The Arch wiki page on the topic is generally applicable to other distros as well: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User

Comment: @wick3dr0se I didn't get if the pid in the `.pid` file is still alive after you've tried restarting it with the detail I put in my answer at the top instead of the `while` loop you have there now. What happens if you `kill` that pid from the command line? Does it stay alive? Why do you start it with `bash script.sh` btw? Just `./script.sh` should be enough if you've set the execution bit on it.