# Kill bash and its child processes

Tags: python, bash, unix

I have a bash file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PWD=/u01/home/dsoria/proyectos/pesables
ENV=$PWD/env/bin/python

echo -e "Obtener Marcas de carnes\n"
$ENV $PWD/src/marca/actualizar_marca.py carnes

echo -e "Obtener Marcas de quesos\n"
$ENV $PWD/src/marca/actualizar_marca.py quesos

echo -e "Obtener Marcas de frios\n"
$ENV $PWD/src/marca/actualizar_marca.py frios

echo -e "Unimos Marcas \n"
$ENV $PWD/src/marca/unir_marcas.py
```

Is there a way to kill the bash process and the current running python script having the bash PID?

Thank you!

If i just kill the bash process it cancels the execution of the subsequent python scripts but it doesn't kill the one running a that time.

Comment: [Don't use all upper case variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and [do quote your variables](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: And don't use `echo -e` with `\n` when just `echo` will do exactly that.

Comment: If you use modern process supervision systems like systemd to run your script, they'll take care of this for you (when sanely configured, systemd shuts down the child process's whole cgroup). That's more effective than solutions you can do from bash itself, because those only work for signals bash can trap -- it can work for SIGTERM, f/e, but not SIGKILL (because SIGKILL can't be trapped at all).

Comment: (typically, btw, you'd just set `PATH=$PWD/env/bin:$PATH` and then you can just run `python` for the rest of your script; similarly, there's no need to refer to `$PWD/...` instead of just `./...`)

Comment: As an alternative approach, see the suggestion I made in a comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859861/kill-all-detached-processes#comment128692677_72859861 (using `fuser -k` to kill all processes having a handle on a lockfile), which applies to your case as much as the one there.